ChartJS Annotations on Horizontal Bar Chart
I am trying to get a Per Bar (or Stack) Line Annotation to show up on a horizontal Bar Chart. simply using the ChartJS documentation example, if you add, "indexAxis: 'y'" it breaks. Is it possible for it to Show Partial Vertical Lines per Bar using the Annotations Plugin?
https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/samples/line/datasetBars.html
Vertical Bars
Horizontal Bars
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
// if you comment below out it works. Clearly from their Docs to get the annotation1-4
  indexAxis: 'y',
    plugins: {
      annotation: {
        annotations: {
          annotation1,
          annotation2,
          annotation3,
          annotation4
        }
      }
    }
  }
};


Below is one of the annotation1 Const, I Tried Swapping the xScaleID to 'y' and the yScaleID 'x' with no success
const annotation1 = {
  type: 'line',
  borderColor: 'green',
  borderWidth: 3,
  label: {
    display: true,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    borderRadius: 0,
    color: 'white',
    content: (ctx) => middleValue(ctx, 0, 0.5).toFixed(0)
  },
  xMax: indexToMax(0) + 0.05,
  xMin: indexToMin(0) - 0.05,
  xScaleID: 'x',
  yMax: (ctx) => middleValue(ctx, 0, 0.5),
  yMin: (ctx) => middleValue(ctx, 0, 0.5),
  yScaleID: 'y'
};


In chart.js (unlike some other charting libraries) x scale is always horizontal and y always vertical so it seems unlikely that the annotations set up for vertical bars will work (be visible) for horizontal bars. If you want help to set up the annotations so that they work for both cases with minimal code duplication, you should post your code, as the required minimal reproducible example - we don't know how your middleValue and indexToMax/Min are implemented, nor should we invent data when you already have it.
